# Javascript accessing variable declared later from a function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, hoisting

Here, lastname const variable is declared later for understanding purpose. it is not accessed from the top in hoistedName obvisously with a hoisting concept. But how can it be read from a function inside?

```
const hoistedName = "Adam" + " " + lastname // cannot read lastname

var hello = (name) => {
  const fullname = name + " " + lastname // can read lastname delared afterward
  console.log(`hello ${fullname}`)
}

const lastname = "Smith" // variable declared

hello("John")  // => hello John Smith

console.log(hoistedName) // => Adam null
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the execution order, because since `hello` is a function it doesn't execute right away, but only when it's called and by the time `hello` is executed, `lastName` has already been given a value. You can verify this by calling `hello` before the variable is initialized:

```
hello('John') // hello John null

const lastname = "Smith" // variable declared

hello("John")  // => hello John Smith

console.log(hoistedName) // => Adam null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was buried in a concept of variable hoisting with var/const/let and function declaration/expression so I was confused. Your explanation really makes sense. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do that. For example: `const hoistedName = () => "Adam" + " " + lastname;`.

```js
const hoistedName = () => "Adam" + " " + lastname; // cannot read lastname

var hello = (name) => {
  const fullname = name + " " + lastname // can read lastname delared afterward
  console.log(`hello ${fullname}`)
}

const lastname = "Smith" // variable declared

hello("John")  // => hello John Smith

console.log(hoistedName()) // => Adam null
```

Comment: Yes, I can understand that it is possible the same way in hello function. I just want to better understand the variable scoping and hoisting.  How is the function scope keeping const/let variables so that they are read to access?

Comment: You can find documentation and some examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp